# Compare values from an ordered list

Tags: python, list, amazon-web-services, beautifulsoup

I started a project with `BeautifulSoup` and need to compare values from an ordered list. See the example below:

```
list = [xxx, 09-11-2020, xxx, 09-13-2020,xxx, 09-09-2020, hhh, 09-10-2020, hhh, 09-11-2020, hhh , 09-15-2020, yyyy, 09-14-20-20,yyyy, 09-15-2020]
```

I need a new list with the values:

```
[xxx, 09-13-2020, hhh, 09-15-2020, yyy, 09-15-2020]
```

I organized them from the smallest to the largest

Comment: What are the `xxx` and so on? It looks like you have many of them and want to remove duplicates? Creating a set out of the list will help with that. Then you can use `sorted`, eg `a=[1, 5, 2]` -> `sorted(a)` yields `[1, 2, 5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`chunked` from the more-itertools library](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) to break the list into pairs, then loop over the pairs to find the largest date for each of the keys, storing it in a dictionary (`last_val`, in the code below). That's probably the most useful form for further processing.

If you do need to convert it back to the interleaved form, you can then format the dates back into strings and flatten the pairs using the [`chain` function from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) back into an iterable (`flattened`, in the code below) or a list.

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import chain

from more_itertools import chunked

data = [
    'xxx', '09-11-2020', 'xxx', '09-13-2020', 'xxx', '09-09-2020', 'hhh',
    '09-10-2020', 'hhh', '09-11-2020', 'hhh', '09-15-2020', 'yyyy',
    '09-14-2020', 'yyyy', '09-15-2020',
]

last_val = {}
for key, date_str in chunked(data, 2):
    date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m-%d-%Y').date()
    if key not in last_val or date > last_val[key]:
        last_val[key] = date

print(last_val)

flattened = chain(*(
    (key, date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
    for key, date in last_val.items()
))

print(list(flattened))
```

Comment: Thanks. 
Now I have this other problem:  "list indices must be integers or slices, not pyodbc.Row"

My code:

from dateutil import parser
from itertools import chain
from more_itertools import chunked

last_val = {}
for key, date_str in chunked(prov, 2):
    date = parser.parse(prov[date_str][1])
    if key not in last_val or date > last_val[key]:
                         last_val[key] = date

Comment: You'll probably need to check what each of the variables along the way contains, although `prov[date_str][1]` looks suspicious here. Otherwise, post a separate question about how to deal with the data you're getting from the database?